# How do I get the perspective of the image whose angle has changed?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

as you can see below, I know the coordinates of 4 points to take a perspective view of a paper.

```
points = [[2181, 378], [3174, 728], [2670, 2088], [1592, 1635]]
```

[image]

Perspective view of the reference image:

[image]

I also know the coordinates of 8 points in the perspective image.

```
transformed_points = [[85, 246], [127, 245], [126, 279], [83, 280], [216, 702], [261, 702], [259, 739], [216, 739]]
```

I want to obtain the same perspective image with the reference perspective image of an image taken from another angle of the same paper. I do not know the corner points. I only know the coordinates of 8 points (Red) in this image.

```
points = [[2339, 719], [2399, 753], [2369, 792], [2308, 759], [2135, 1384], [2199, 1425], [2166, 1471], [2100, 1430]]
```

[image]

I can match these points 1-1, but a part of the picture doesn't fit properly. And I get an output like below
[image: Perspective image]

How can I get the perspective image of the image whose angle changes, to be the same as the reference image using 8 points?

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    scale = 5
    width_mm = 130 * scale
    height_mm = 190 * scale
    rect = np.array(pts, dtype='float32')

    dst = np.float32([[0, 0], [width_mm, 0], [width_mm, height_mm], [0, height_mm]])
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (width_mm, height_mm), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return warped

ref_image_path = "images/ref.jpg"
ref_image = cv2.imread(ref_image_path)
ref_transform_points = [[2181, 378], [3174, 728], [2670, 2088], [1592, 1635]]
warped_ref = four_point_transform(ref_image, ref_transform_points)
cv2.imwrite("images/warped_ref.jpg", warped_ref)
```

Comment: Different errors go into the result, imperfection of the point coordinates, lens distortion, non-planarity, etc. If you can spread the reference point over a bigger area, the errors should divide better over the whole image.

Comment: You are right, in this image we assume that the camera is in a fixed position, and no lens distortion. Unfortunately, we can not spread the reference points.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation from one perspective to the other is given by an homographic transformation of the form:

```
X = (ax + by + c) / (gx + hy + 1)
Y = (dx + ey + f) / (gx + hy + 1)
```

These equations can be linearized as

```
ax + by + c - g xX - hyX = X
dx + ey + f - g xY - hyY = Y
```

Now you form a linear system of 8 equations in 8 unknowns, using 4 matching points in two images. Make sure that they are not aligned.

Preferably, take the 4 corners of the frame, the two groups of 4 points will yield low accuracy. You can use the 8 points and a least-squares scheme, but I am not sure that this is enough.